# In Kevinastone Django Angularjs tutorial resources under bower_components are not loaded in the browser

Tags: django, angularjs

I am trying to learn django and angularjs combination using the tutorial provided at http://blog.kevinastone.com/getting-started-with-django-rest-framework-and-angularjs.html. The problem is the resources under 'bower_components' folder are not loaded in the browser. However the components under 'assets' folder are loaded in the browser. Has anybody come across this problem or is it that I have to copy them under the assets folder and continue working, thereby leaving this problem as it is.